# Can the getFile Method of the DirectoryEntry delete an existing file if found?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm currently creating text files with code similar to the following. This will create a file just fine, but it won't delete an existing file.

```
fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: false},
   function(fileentry) {
      fileentry.createWriter(function (filewriter) {
         filewriter.write('Hello world!');
      });
   }
);
```

**Any way of deleting an existing file cleanly without too much extra code or dedicated deletion code?**

I've been using this guide but with no luck finding an efficient way of doing this.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as I can get. It checks for the file, removes if it's there. It also captures the error if it cannot be removed. If by the end of all that, there is space for the new file, it is created as before.

```
fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: false},
   function(fileentry) {
      fileentry.remove(createfile, errorhandler);
   },
   createfile
);

function createfile(){
   //either the file was never there or has been removed successfully

   fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: false},
      function(fileentry) {
         fileentry.createWriter(function (filewriter) {
            filewriter.write('Hello world!');
         });
      }
   );
}

function errorhandler(error){
   //file already exists and couldn't be removed
}
```

It's not as compact nor and *pretty* as I'd have liked, but it's the best I can come up with for now.

Answer (score -1):

This should work much like your writer does:

```
fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: false}, function(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.remove(function() {
      console.log('File deleted.');
    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);
```

Comment: I was hoping not to need a separate chunk of code to do a delete. I'd ideally like to only use the getFile method once.

Comment: I just had a thought too, I would have to nest the file creation inside the success function of this code wouldn't I? Otherwise, the file creation code might start running BEFORE this code has run!